# How to do two queries and combine to one answer?

Tags: sql-server

My tables look like this: [tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am2mp.png)
Output needs to look like this: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCE3R.png)

But with my current code all I get is a blank answer nothing under Gamer or gsExperiencePoints. I believe I need to separate the questions and then combine the answer, but I'm not quite sure how to go about that would anyone be able to explain how to do that (I don't want the answer)

```
SELECT
    gamerFirst + ' ' + gamerLast as 'Gamer',
    gsExperiencePoints
FROM GAMER
    JOIN GAME_STAT ON GAMER.gamerID = GAME_STAT.gamerID
        JOIN GAME ON GAME_STAT.gameID = GAME.gameID
            JOIN DEVELOPER ON GAME.devID = DEVELOPER.devID
WHERE devName = 'Blizzard Entertainment' AND gsExperiencePoints = (SELECT MAX(gsExperiencePoints) AS gsExperiencePoints FROM GAME_STAT)
GROUP BY gsExperiencePoints, gamerFirst, gamerLast
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only need `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 gamerFirst + ' ' + gamerLast AS Gamer,
       gsExperiencePoints
FROM GAMER g JOIN
     GAME_STAT gs
     ON g.gamerID = gs.gamerID JOIN
     GAME g
     ON gs.gameID = g.gameID JOIN
     DEVELOPER d
     ON g.devID = d.devID
WHERE devName = 'Blizzard Entertainment'
ORDER BY gsExperiencePoints DESC;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not able to use TOP 1 (I was told not to), I need to do two queries and then combine it. I was told to split it up and then bring them together.